# Scroll for find element in Selenium

Tags: selenium, scroll

Hi I tried to scrall for found an element in Selenium:

I found that : `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrallIntoView();",link)`

But I have an error:

```
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: arguments[0].scrallIntoView is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.127)
```

My code is:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://cordis.europa.eu/search/fr?q=contenttype%3D%27project%27%20AND%20programme%2Fcode%3D%27H2020%27&p=1&num=10&srt=/project/contentUpdateDate:decreasing')
driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(10)

link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="c-main"]/div/div/section[2]/section[2]/app-card-search[1]/div/div[2]/a')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrallIntoView();",link)
link.click()

time.sleep(5)

projet = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/app-root/ng-component/main/section/app-header-project/div/div/div[2]/h1')
print(projet.text)

driver.back()
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a typo on your script `scrallIntoView()`.
Changing it with *`scrollIntoView()`* should work.

Comment: Thanks i am tired go to rest for me.